Loading Button is not Visible
I am Getting this problem and did not find the solution can anyone figure out i added the MHLoading button and its working as i wanted but problem is that the loading is not visible when loading starts then the title is not showing and loading stops title is showing but loading circle is not visible
 @IBAction func btnRephrasePressed(_ sender: LoadingButton) {
        print("Mode: \(selectedMode ?? "Default"), Tone: \(selectedTone)")
        sender.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        sender.isLoading = true
        sender.setNeedsDisplay()
       
        
        APIRequests.rephraseText(textView.text, mode: selectedMode ?? "rephrase", tone: selectedTone) { data, response, error in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                sender.isLoading = false
                sender.setTitle("Rephrase", for: .normal)
                
            }

            if response == .success {
                if let str = data as? String {
                    let controller = ResultViewController.loadNib()
                    controller.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
                    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
                    controller.genText = str
                    
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.present(controller, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                
                print("Error: \(error ?? "An unknown error occurred")")
            }
        }
    }



We don't know what your APIRequests.rephraseText() function does or how it is structured, so it's impossible to know for sure what's going on. If that function does time-consuming work on the main thread then that is your problem. Your call to setNeedsDisplay() will not have any effect until your code returns and the app's event loop is serviced.

Maybe you need make this:
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sender.isLoading = false
            sender.setTitle("Rephrase", for: .normal)
            sender.setNeedsLayout()  //  refreshes the change
        }

Another cause can you check is the alpha visibility in the spinner
